# Installing outdoor ceiling fan on stucco, no electric box

Tags: patio, fans, stucco

I’m wanting to install an outdoor ceiling fan on my back patio, the covered area is stucco and there currently isn’t an electrical box. Don’t know where studs are either. Is this an easy DIY or should I contact an electrician to handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to require several things, some of which an electrican will do, and some of which an electrician won't do (or won't be cost effective for if they will do.) Whether you can do them all, we don't know, you might.

1. Get power to the location from somewhere there is power.
2. Provide physical support for a fan box.
3. Almost certainly repair stucco from damage required to get 1&2 done.

Your question does not mention having wiring but no box, so I assume 1 applies. 2 certainly applies and 3 is all-but-certain to apply. Paying electrician rates to do stucco repair is not recommended. Even if the stucco person charges the same rate, that one has the experience in that process...

You've provided additional information that there is an attic space above, which should allow avoiding stucco repair, if the wiring and support work can be accomplished from above.

Comment: Awesome!!!! I will check it out this evening and hopefully I can access the space from the attic and it will be an easy, cheap install for me!